# keras model subclassing examples

Tags: tensorflow, keras

starting Keras 2.2.0, the 3rd API of model definition is released: Model subclassing.

According to the FAQ:

> However, in subclassed models, the model's topology is defined as
>   Python code (rather than as a static graph of layers). That means the
>   model's topology cannot be inspected or serialized. As a result, the
>   following methods and attributes are not available for subclassed
>   models:
>
> model.inputs and model.outputs. model.to_yaml() and model.to_json()
>   model.get_config() and model.save().

The only option to save the trained model for inference is to use **model.save_weights** method. However, I have not had luck in loading the model back for inference. Encountered error messages include:

> This model has never been called, thus its weights have not yet been created, so no summary can be displayed. Build the model first (e.g. by calling it on some test data).
>   You are trying to load a weight file containing 4 layers into a model with 0 layers.
>   NotImplementedError

Can anyone give a full toy example for creating a subclassed keras model, train, and save_weights, then load it back for inference?

Comment: tf.keras also says "Caution: Subclassed models are not serializable because their architecture is defined by the Python code in the body of the call method."

Comment: If you are using `TF2.1` or later you can use `model.save`, `tf.saved_model.save` and `save_weights` and `load_weights` are three different approaches listed in the guidelines section on [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize). Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You need to call the tf.keras.Model.build method before you try to save a subclassed model weights. An alternative to this would be calling tf.keras.Model.fit or tf.keras.Model.fit.call on some inputs before you try to save your model weights. This same applies to load weights into a newly created instance of your subclassed model. you need to call one of the above-mentioned methods before you try to load your weights.
Here is an example showing both saving and loading weights for a subclassed model

```
import tensorflow as tf

print('TensorFlow', tf.__version__)

class ResidualBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, block_type=None, n_filters=None):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.n_filters = n_filters
        if block_type == 'identity':
            self.strides = 1
        elif block_type == 'conv':
            self.strides = 2
            self.conv_shorcut = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.n_filters, 
                               kernel_size=1, 
                               padding='same',
                               strides=self.strides,
                               kernel_initializer='he_normal')
            self.bn_shortcut = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)

        self.conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.n_filters, 
                               kernel_size=3, 
                               padding='same',
                               strides=self.strides,
                               kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.bn_1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)
        self.relu_1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()

        self.conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.n_filters, 
                               kernel_size=3, 
                               padding='same', 
                               kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.bn_2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)
        self.relu_2 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        shortcut = x
        if self.strides == 2:
            shortcut = self.conv_shorcut(x)
            shortcut = self.bn_shortcut(shortcut)
        y = self.conv_1(x)
        y = self.bn_1(y)
        y = self.relu_1(y)
        y = self.conv_2(y)
        y = self.bn_2(y)
        y = tf.add(shortcut, y)
        y = self.relu_2(y)
        return y

class ResNet34(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, include_top=True, n_classes=1000):
        super(ResNet34, self).__init__()

        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.include_top = include_top
        self.conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, 
                                               kernel_size=7, 
                                               padding='same', 
                                               strides=2, 
                                               kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.bn_1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)
        self.relu_1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        self.maxpool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(3, 2, padding='same')
        self.residual_blocks = tf.keras.Sequential()
        for n_filters, reps, downscale in zip([64, 128, 256, 512], 
                                              [3, 4, 6, 3], 
                                              [False, True, True, True]):
            for i in range(reps):
                if i == 0 and downscale:
                    self.residual_blocks.add(ResidualBlock(block_type='conv', 
                                                              n_filters=n_filters))
                else:
                    self.residual_blocks.add(ResidualBlock(block_type='identity', 
                                                              n_filters=n_filters))
        self.GAP = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=self.n_classes)

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        y = self.conv_1(x)
        y = self.bn_1(y)
        y = self.relu_1(y)
        y = self.maxpool(y)
        y = self.residual_blocks(y)
        if self.include_top:
            y = self.GAP(y)
            y = self.fc(y)
        return y

## saving weights
model = ResNet34()
model.build((1, 224, 224, 3))
model.summary()
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')

## loading saved weights
model_new = ResNet34()
model_new.build((1, 224, 224, 3))
model_new.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
```

Comment: good answer. the key is build() method to actually initialise layers in a subclassed Model, otherwise the computation graph isn't built.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let `ResidualBlock` inherit from tf.keras.layers.Layer rather than tf.keras.Model? Or this is done so one can just make a model from a ResidualBlock and then call the fit method, etc ...

Comment: @Andy Yes you are correct, Implementing `ResidualBlock`  as a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` would be more accurate.