# How to set the input of a keras subclass model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, subclass

I've created a keras subclass model using tensorflow. Snippets are shown below.

```py
class SubModel(Model):
    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs)

model = SubModel()
model.fit(data, labels, ...)
```

When `fit` the model, it will get the inputs and input_shape itself. What I want to do is pass inputs to the model myself.Just like the functional API does.

```py
inputs = tf.keras.input(shape=(100,))
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to be able to specify the shape of the inputs in advance? Maybe using the `build` method of the subclassing API will help.

Comment: Yes, I just want to specify the shape and name of the inputs in advance, and pass inputs to the model. You mean call  `build` method just like `model.build` ? Or other usages? I'm a little confused.

Comment: The `Model` class has a `build` method which is called to allow the model weights to be created (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823828/4332585). If it has not been called before, it will be called the first time the model is used (to fit or predict or evaluate). You could call it beforehand with the shape you need, but I am not sure what you would gain from it if your input shape is always the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that?

```
model_ = SubModel()
inputs = tf.keras.input(shape=(100,))
outputs = model_(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I think that is a little weird. I mean I've created the model but now I use another `Model` to wrap it. It just like the functional API does.

Comment: In this way, using `model.summary` will only show the input layer and model layer itself and not show the inner layer of the model.

Comment: Anyway, with a subclassing API, the `summary` method won't work (see: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25036#issuecomment-504125711).

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi, actually we can. Prior to printing shape with `summary`, we feed fake data first, see [here](https://github.com/dtransposed/Paper-Implementation/blob/eed841fcbfd94bcc19de727164877e12a75be4dc/action_recognition_using_visual_attention/utils.py#L103)

Comment: @donto you are right. You can even just build the model with undefined shapes (with defined rank).

Comment: I am working on a transfer learning task using this guide: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/ and in a block of code, it exactly does the same thing: `x = base_model(inputs, training=False)` but as @Alexander pointed out, once the model is built, `model.summary()` does not show the layers of the inner model whereas I want to be able to see all of them. I later want to use them to display activations at each layer. I am still trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: be aware of capital "I" in `tf.keras.Input()`

Answer (score 4):

I ended up giving up on keras.Model subclassing. It was too tricky and I was getting errors about input shape.

I wanted to be able to use `.fit()` directly on my custom class model objects.
For this purpose, an easy method I found was to implement the builtin `__getattr__` method (more info in [official Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)).

With this, it is possible to use any method of `keras.Model` on our custom objects. The class implementation I use:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Input, layers, Model

class SubModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = self.get_model()

    def get_model(self):
        # here we use the usual Keras functional API
        x = Input(shape=(24, 24, 3))
        y = layers.Conv2D(28, 3, strides=1)(x)
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=[y])

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        This method enables to access an attribute/method of self.model.
        Thus, any method of keras.Model() can be used transparently from a SubModel object
        """
        return getattr(self.model, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    submodel = SubModel()
    submodel.fit(data, labels, ...)  # underlyingly calls SubModel.model.fit()
```

Explanation: `__getattr__` is a special Python method called when the default attribute access fails, i.e. when `name` doesn't belong to `self`. In these cases, we try to access the attribute `name` of **self.model**.

Comment: A solid workaround.

Comment: what is ```getattr()```

Comment: `getattr(self.model, name)` access the attribute `name` of self.model.

Comment: This is a very good solution that actually achieves what people think of when they want to make a subclass but doesn't seem possible with keras.Model subclassing. I'm only wondering if there are some catches that would make it a bad practice. It has some `eval`-vibes to it (obviously not really but still), but I have no idea. Would love to hear some more opinions on this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to specify the input shape before calling `model.fit`, you can use `model.build` It takes one positional parameter: `input_shape`.

Unrelated (but in case other people have this issue), you need to do this whenever you want to call `model.summary` or sometimes with Dense layers, e.g:

`ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to "Dense" should be defined. Found "None".`

As an example:

```
class MyModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        # Example layers that would through an error if we didn't call build
        self.convT1 = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=10)
        self.dense = keras.layers.Dense(10)

        self.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics='acc')

        # ! Call build and pass the input_shape
        self.build(input_shape)
        self.summary() # Because we can now! (would fail without self.build)
model = MyModel(input_shape=(1, 1, 10, 10))
```

You could also call `model.build` after initialization instead of `self.build`.

Comment: ```self.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics='acc'))``` it is not correct, it should be ```self.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse', metrics='acc')``` and the code is not working！